H_2 Hamiltonian matrix off diagonal elements between RHF state and open shell
I am currently trying to calculate the Hamiltonian matrix of the H$_2$ molecule. To describe that I use the second quantized molecular Hamiltonian:
$\hat{H} = \sum_\sigma\sum_{pq} h_{pq} a_{p\sigma}^\dagger a_{q\sigma} + \frac12 \sum_{\sigma\tau}\sum_{pqrs} g_{pqrs} a_{p\sigma}^\dagger a_{r\tau}^\dagger a_{s\tau}a_{q\sigma} + h_{nuc}$
I get the $h$,$g$,$h_{nuc}$ elements from PySCF mol.intor('int1e_kin'), mol.intor('int1e_nuc'), mol.intor('int2e'), mol.energy_nuc() and the overlap between AOs with mol.intor('int1e_ovlp'). We therefore do the calculatino at HF level (mean field).
The states I am considering for the basis of the Hamiltonian matrix are the first the RHF ground state. And second the diradical open shell singlet which corresponds to the CSF $\mathcal{O}^{2,1}_{0,0}(S_L,S_R)$. We define these states using Lowdin (symmetric) orbitals which are orthogonalised AOs. We define the determinants in Lowdin basis as follows $|S_LS_R\overline{S}_L\overline{S}_R\rangle$ (I know this is not the most common convention but I'm using a code that uses this convention for another part). The states are defined with this orbital basis and ordering as follows (RHF need to have basis change)
$|RHF\rangle = | \sigma_g \overline{\sigma}_g \rangle = \frac12 (|1001\rangle + |0110\rangle + |1010\rangle + |0101\rangle)$ since $\langle \sigma_g |S_L \rangle = \langle \sigma_g |S_R \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
$|\mathcal{O}^{2,1}_{0,0}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|1001\rangle + |0110\rangle) \equiv | \phi \rangle$
With that I can now calculate $\langle RHF | \hat{H} | \phi \rangle \equiv H_{12}$
I know that this value should go to zero as the internuclear distance increase because the system is going to go to the diradical state during separation (which means the eigenvector needs to be $[1,0]$ and therefore $H_{12}$ needs to be 0 in the 2x2 matrix).
$\textbf{The problem I have is that I don't get 0}$ I get a value around -0.6 and I can't find why.
To do the calculation I transform the $h$, $g$ matrix given by PySCF from AO basis to Lowdin basis then calculate the 1 and 2 RDMS and add all the terms. Here is how it looks like for $H_{12}$
$H_{12} = \frac{1}{2^{3/2}}\bigg[ h_{11} + h_{22} + 0.5(g_{1122} + g_{2211}) + h_{nuc} +  0.5(g_{2112} + g_{2221}) + h_{12} + 0.5(g_{1112} + g_{1211} + h_{21} + 0.5(g_{2122} + g_{2221}) + 0.5(g_{1221} + g_{2112}) + h_{22} + h_{11} + 0.5(g_{2211} + g_{1122}) + h_{nuc}) + h_{12} + 0.5(g_{1211} + g_{1112}) + h_{21} + g_{2221} + g_{2122}\bigg]$
where $g$, $h$ are in Lowdin basis
Is there anything wrong with this expression ? Or with the basis transform etc. I can't find what is going wrong.
for reference I use the basis STO-3G. And the change of basis of $h$, $g$ is done using the following
$| \psi_{\alpha} \rangle = \sum_i | \phi_i \rangle \langle \phi_i| \psi_\alpha \rangle  = \sum_i c_{\alpha i} | \phi_i \rangle$
$h_{\alpha\beta} = \sum_i \sum_j c_{\alpha i}^* c_{\beta j} h_{ij}$
$g_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta} = \sum_{ijkl} c_{\alpha i}^*c_{\beta j}c_{\gamma k}^*c_{\delta l} \ g_{ijkl}$
